# Make 4 edit boxes total sum never to exceed 100

Tags: java, editbox

How could I make my four edit boxes total sum never to exceed 100? None of the edit box values or the total sum of the edit boxes should also never go below 0.

Comment: How about printing an error message if the sum conditions are violated?

Comment: textwatcher is your friend... and also maybe check some "losing focus" functions... You need to come up with  lgic to divide 100 between 3 boxes/numbers..

Comment: @TheLostMind - I know how to do it between two boxes, but now when it's four I'm totally stuck.

Comment: @user2481390 - first comeup with an algorithm to efficiently divide the 4 numbers to form a sum of 100... for example if you enter 90 in the first box, you should be allowed to enter anything between 1 and 8 in the second.. I think you get the point.. The android part is just puting your logic in a textwatcher and focus based functions..

Comment: @TheLostMind - I'm not using android, so I do not know what a textwatcher is or focus based functions...

Comment: @user2481390 - oops... :)..